# Apache Ivy Error ${jdom.version}

Tags: ivy, artifactory

I am getting an error during a build. The project is using Apache IVY and uses Artifactory.[image: IVY error]

I am unable to understand what $(jdom.version} means.
Apparently the same build works without errors on a different machine and 
$(jdom.version} resolves to 1.

How do I debug this issue

Answer (score 2):

This is a [variable](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#variables) that defined in another file (probably, `build.xml`), which is present on the "different" machine but on this one.